PCF with Google Maps JS API doesn't work in Canvas App
I'm building a pcf control to display Google Map with three location markers A, B, C and trace best route to go from A to C with B as a waypoint, also applies some custom style to markers and route lines. I'm using Google Maps JavaScript API and React. The control works perfectly in the test harness and in model driven apps, but when try to use it in canvas app, it doesn't show right the map, neither the location markers, nor the route. I let some screenshots of the control.
I found this post with maybe some related problem but with ArcGIS maps: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Pro-Dev-ISV/Power-App-Component-Framework-with-ArcGis-Embed/m-p/400343
I think, can be a posible conflict with some native JS library in canvas app.
Maybe someone has faced this issue before?
PCF Test Environment:

Test Canvas App:

JS console logs:

Thanks!
I try the pcf control in PCF test environment and model driven app and works properly
